# How to read text file in an array then find if line has more values assigned to it and display the data

Tags: java, arrays

need help with reading files into arrays and if the text file contains more entries on a line how to display that:

```
students.txt

5678,Ben Over,300,D,78,582,H,85,141,P,52

2345,Dan Driff,301,P,56,358,P,52,314,P,50

3898,Illene Over,308,D,82,582,C,70

4567,Laura Norder,581,C,71
```

This text file show be stored in array like this:
(Studentid,Fname Sname,[unit num,grade,mark])

Example first line has 3 units for that student, where the last line has 1 unit

---

```
5678,Ben Over,300,D,78,582,H,85,141,P,52

Studentid,Fname Sname,[unit num,grade,mark],[unit num,grade,mark],[unit num,grade,mark]
```

---

```
4567,Laura Norder,581,C,71

Studentid,Fname Sname,[unit num,grade,mark]
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++)
        {
            int Studentid = inputFile.nextInt();
            String Fname = inputFile.next();
            String Lname = inputFile.next();

            int unitNum = inputFile.nextInt();
            String grade = inputFile.next();
            int mark = inputFile.next();

    student[i] = new student(Studentid, Fname, Lname,unitNum,grade,mark);

    System.out.println(student[i].getSID() + student[i].getFname()...student[i].getmark()); 
        }
```

With this code, I know it will only print student with 1 unit assigned to it, for example, it will work with the last line of the text file, however it will not work with the other lines that have more than 1 unit assigned to the student.

My question is how to I get the code to find if there are more units assigned to that student and display it. For example, students can have a MAX of 10 units assigned to them.

Appreciate your help! :)

Also not sure how to question my question, if you think of an appropriate title I will rename it.

Comment: You could split the line into an array on each comma then get the length of the array to determine how many units are assigned.

Comment: I have split my code using (",") which separates the value but I am unable to show if the students have more than 1 unit, it comes up as an error and it will only display the following: [ 5678,Ben Over,300,D,78 ] but not the rest of the line [ 582,H,85,141,P,52 ] as the first line has two more units assigned to the person.

Comment: Wait so you split the line on commas, and it didn't split the whole line? Sounds like something isn't right. Show your splitting code.

Comment: Scanner s = new Scanner(studentFile).useDelimiter(",|\r\n");

Comment: Do not use `Scanner`, but if you still want to use it, then check for more, like `inputFile.hasNext()`...

Comment: I am currently trying the inputFile.hasNext() ... essentially I just want to program to display StudentId, StudentName and their units (whether they have 1 unit or 10 units). Still having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: @Summer Scanner is a bit weird. If you still want to use Scanner, I would suggest use scanner.nextLine() which will give you the enitre string. Then split the string by using String.split() API

Comment: Ok so I have implemented the Split method and now prints values on each line:  for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
  String p = inputFile.nextLine();
  String q = p;
  String[] split = p.split(",");
  
  for(String s : split){
   System.out.println(s);
  }
  } //this works but this is where I am stuck and I need to assign the values that uses a constructor from another class (the student[i] = new student(sId, name ... mark)) how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would parse a file like that using an array of arrays for the units. Like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    File studentFile = new File("students.txt");
    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(studentFile).useDelimiter("\n");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.exit(1);}

    ArrayList<String> students_temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> students = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    int count = 0; // Number of students
    while (scanner.hasNext() == true) {

        students_temp.add(scanner.nextLine());
        count++;

    }

    student[] student_array = new student[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < students_temp.size(); i++) {
        // Add each entry in the students_temp variable to the students list as a list of strings
        students.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(students_temp.get(i).split("\\s*,\\s*"))));
        // Student info
        int Studentid = Integer.parseInt(students.get(i).get(0));
        String[] name = students.get(i).get(1).split("\\s");
        String Fname = name[0];
        String Lname = name[1];
        String[][] units = new String[(students.get(i).size()-2)/3][3]; // The units the student has, as an array of arrays
        // Floats because we need real division
        float element = 2; // The element in students.get(i)
        float unit = 0; // The unit we are on eg: [300, D, 78]
        float item = 0; // The item within the unit eg: D
        boolean isFirst = true;
        while (element < students.get(i).size()) {
            if ((((element - 2)/3) % 1 == 0) && (!isFirst))
                unit++;
            if (item > 2)
                item = 0;
            units[(int)unit][(int)item] = students.get(i).get((int)element);
            item++;
            element++;
            isFirst = false;
        }
        student_array[i] = new student(Studentid, Fname, Lname, units);
    }
}
```

So what I did here was read in the file to an ArrayList because we don't know how many students there are beforehand. Then I made an array to hold all the students once they are parsed correctly. Next we loop over all the students in `students_temp` and split (on commas) those strings into an ArrayList. Getting the ID, first name and last name of the student is trivial because the format is standard. Here's a walk through of how I got the units dynamically:

1. Initialize the array of arrays for the units based on the length of the student's `ArrayList`
2. Initialize all the variables we'll need for the loop

   - `element` - The current element in the student's `ArrayList`, starting at 2 so we skip the ID and the name
   - `unit` The unit we are on
   - `item` the item in the unit we're on
   - `isFirst` when we loop around first, we don't want unit incrementing or we get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`
3. Loop over the student's `ArrayList` until we've run out of items

   - If (element - 2)/3 divides evenly into 3 and it's not the first time around, increment unit
   - If item > 2, then go back to 0 because units are only 3 in length
   - Assign the correct element from the student's `ArrayList` to the correct unit
   - Increment `item`, `element` and set `isFirst` to false
4. Lastly, Add the new student to the array of students

You'll have to modify your student constructor to take an array of arrays but that should be trivial. Also, by convention class names start with a capital letter, so your `student` class should be `Student`.

EDIT: @Summer: in this line:

```
units[(int)unit][(int)item] = students.get(i).get((int)element);
```

I cast the `floats`, `unit` and `item` to `int` then pass them in as indexes because you cannot pass a `float` as an index. Then I assign the value of the index of `element` (also casted) in the students `ArrayList` to `units` at the index of `unit` and `item`.

Comment: Nice code, could you explain the line  where is says: units[(int)unit][(int)item] = students.get(i).get((int)element); and my constructor looks like this now: public Student(int sid, String fname, String lname, String[][] units) {
  studentID = sid;
  name = fname;
  name = lname;
  arr = units[grade][mark];
  
 } // I think more constructor is wrong

Comment: See my edit for the explanation of that line. You should post another question about your constructor, that looks like a whole other topic.